# Cannot append HTMLDivElement to HTMLUnknownElement in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, dom, knockout.js

I have app that is used knockoutJs. There I have custom components. But for some reasons there are errors like `WrongDocument`.

In library there are some pease of code:

```
domNode.appendChild(childNodes[i]);
```

where `domNode` is my component `HTMLUnknownElement` and its `ownerDocument` - is my DOM
`childNodes[i]` - is template of component and it's `ownerDocument` isn't my DOM. It's more like:

```
<html><head><title></title><base href="https://localhost:44040/user/Details"></head><body></body></html>
```

Can this error be due to not the same `ownerDocuments`? And how it can be resolved?

For other browsers it works fine.

Comment: Show some more code. Would be great to have some sample code that recreates the error.

Comment: Can you share the errors and a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @epascarello, yes, I would like, but creating a simple jsFiddle example cannot reproduce my issue for now. Looks like in jsFiddle item to add from same DOM

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: @epascarello "SCRIPT5022: WrongDocumentError"

Comment: sounds like importNode needs to be used. Hard to tell you the solution without more context.

Comment: Can not reproduce the problem on my side, so, if you could post enough code to reproduce the problem, it might be easier for us to narrow down the problem. Besides, I suggest you could try to use [JQuery .append](https://api.jquery.com/append/) method to add htmlstring or elements.